# Delete the records repeated by date, and keep the oldest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, and it returns the following result, I need to delete the records repeated by date, and keep the oldest, how could I do this?

```
select 
    a.EMP_ID, a.EMP_DATE, 
from 
    EMPLOYES a 
inner join
    TABLE2 b on a.table2ID = b.table2ID and b.ID_TYPE = 'E' 
where 
    a.ID = 'VJAHAJHSJHDAJHSJDH' 
    and year(a.DATE) = 2021 
    and month(a.DATE) = 1 
    and a.ID <> 31 
order by 
    a.DATE;
```

[image]

Additionally, I would like to fill in the missing days of the month ... and put them empty if I don't have that data, can this be done?

I would appreciate if you could guide me to solve this problem

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a calendar table (a table with a list of dates of every day from eg 1970, until 2099) ? If not, make one - it's a handy thing to have around. add an incrementing number column too

Comment: Hi, i don't have a calendar table ...

Comment: I suggest you make one. Calculating arbitrary rowsets in SQLS is tedious and a waste of resources. Makes queries like this a doddle (you left join your data to the calendar table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers miss some of the requirement..

Initial step - **do this once only**. Make a calendar table. This will come in handy for all sorts of things over the time:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = '2000';
DECLARE @YearCnt INT = 50 ;
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, '01','01')
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, @YearCnt, @StartDate));

;WITH Cal(n) AS
(
SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM Cal
WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
),
FnlDt(d, n) AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate), n FROM Cal
),
FinalCte AS
(
SELECT
[D] = CONVERT(DATE,d),
[Dy] = DATEPART(DAY, d),
[Mo] = DATENAME(MONTH, d),
[Yr] = DATEPART(YEAR, d),
[DN] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d),
[N] = n

FROM FnlDt
)
SELECT * INTO Cal FROM finalCte
ORDER BY [Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

<sup>credit: mostly [this site](https://sqlskull.com/2020/05/21/generate-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)</sup>

Now we can write some simple query to stick your data (with one small addition) onto it:

```
--your query, minus the date bits in the WHERE, and with a ROW_NUMBER
WITH yourQuery AS(
  SELECT a.emp_id, a.emp_date, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(a.emp_date AS DATE) ORDER BY a.emp_date) rn
  FROM EMPLOYES a 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 b on a.table2ID = b.table2ID 
  WHERE a.emp_id = 'VJAHAJHSJHDAJHSJDH' AND a.id <> 31 AND b.id_type = 'E' 
)

--your query, left joined onto the cal table so that you get a row for every day even if there is no emp data for that day
SELECT c.d, yq.*
FROM 
  Cal c
  LEFT JOIN yourQuery yq 
  ON 
    c.d = CAST(yq.emp_date AS DATE) AND --cut the time off
    yq.rn = 1                           --keep only the earliest time per day
WHERE
  c.d BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND EOMONTH('2021-01-01')
```

We add a rownumbering to your table, it restarts every time the date changes and counts up in order of time. We make this into a CTE (or a subquery, CTE is cleaner) then we simply left join it to the calendar table. This means that for any date you don't have data, you still have the calendar date. For any days you do have data, the rownumber `rn` being a condition of the join means that only the first datetime from each day is present in the results

Note: **something is wonky about your question** . You said you `SELECT a.emp_id` and your results show 'VJAHAJHSJHDAJHSJDH' is the emp id, but your where clause says `a.id` twice, once as a string and once as a number - this can't be right, so I've guessed at fixing it but I suspect you have translated your query into something for SO, perhaps to hide real column names.. Also your SELECT has a dangling comma that is a syntax error.

If you have translated/obscured your real query, *make absolutely sure* you understand any answer here when translating it back. It's very frustrating when someone is coming back and saying "hi your query doesn't work" then it turns out that *they* damaged it trying to translate it back to their own db, because they hid the real column names in the question..

FInally, do not use functions on table data in a where clause; it generally kills indexing. Always try and find a way of leaving table data alone. Want all of january? Do like I did, and say `table.datecolumn BETWEEN firstofjan AND endofjan` etc - SQLserver at least stands a chance of using an index for this, rather than calling a function on every date in the table, *every time the query is run*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the last part of making the join with the calendar table helped me a lot, I have solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT a.EMP_ID, a.EMP_DATE, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.EMP_ID, CAST(a.DATE as Date) ORDER BY a.DATE ASC)
    from EMPLOYES a INNER JOIN TABLE2 b 
        on a.table2ID = b.table2ID 
        and b.ID_TYPE = 'E' 
    where a.ID = 'VJAHAJHSJHDAJHSJDH' 
    and year(a.DATE) = 2021 
    and MONTH(a.DATE) = 1 
    and a.ID <> 31
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: 1) You forgot the gaps part, 2) use date ranges rather than calling functions like YEAR and MONTH on table data in the where

Comment: @CaiusJard: thanks, have a look again. OP wants to group by EMP_ID and Date?

Answer (score 1):

Try with an aggregate function MAX or MIN

```
create table #tmp(dt datetime, val numeric(4,2))

insert into #tmp values ('2021-01-01 10:30:35', 1)
insert into #tmp values ('2021-01-02 10:30:35', 2)
insert into #tmp values ('2021-01-02 11:30:35', 3)
insert into #tmp values ('2021-01-03 10:35:35', 4)

select * from #tmp

select tmp.*
from #tmp tmp
inner join 
    (select max(dt) as dt, cast(dt as date) as dt_aux from #tmp group by cast(dt as date)) compressed_rows on
        tmp.dt = compressed_rows.dt

drop table #tmp
```

results:
[image]